# Indy FTP Client OnStatus not getting Disconnect events

Tags: events, ftp, client, indy, disconnect

I have setup an Indy IdFTP Client to a FileZilla FTP Server.The client tries to Connect on startup of my app and, If it fails, keeps retrying every few seconds for the lifetime of the app. In addition, I need to detect if I lose the connection and, again, keep trying to re-establish the connection. This is where I am having a problem.
I have added an OnStatus event handler which seems to fire for all the event types except hsDisconnecting and hsDisconnected. 
I also have an OnDisconnected event handler which only fires when I have locked the Server, in this case, when I try to connect, it fires the OnConnected then immediately fires the OnDisconnected. However, if I set the Server as not Active after the initial successful connection, the server tells me it has disconnected me but I do not get an event in my code so I don't know I need to start trying to connect again? Am I wrong in expecting these events in this scenario, is there something else I should be listening for?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Forgot to say, I am using Indy 11.0

Comment: You should add a major tag like delphi (what I would suspect) to make your question be in focus.